# Testing for significant differences in Likert-type data, including random factors

Tags: r, statistical-significance, likert, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have data from a number of subjects who rated conditions 1 through 8 on a Likert-type ordinal scale (from “much worse” to “much better”, here, coded from -3 to 3). It results in the following counts of occurrences:

```
    -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
  1  1  2  8 18 46 28 17
  2 13 15 47 24 17  2  2
  3  0  5 13 21 39 24 18
  4  0  5 12 25 40 26 12
  5 12 12 40 32 17  5  2
  6 12 12 42 31 13  9  1
  7  0  8 13 60 17 20  2
  8  0  9 23 54 21 10  3
```

Obviously, I also have the data in a regular format, where each row is a combination of subject, condition, and rating.

**How can I tell whether some condition pairs are significantly different from each other in terms of their ratings?**

For example, I may want to look at comparing conditions 3 and 4, as well as 5 and 6, since they seem very similar.

Now, typically – at least in our field – people would go ahead and calculate an average rating per condition over all subjects, and then compare those means using T-tests or an ANOVA for the entire experimental design. I'm quite sure this is *not* the way to go, since the scale itself is ordinal (so, a no-no for calculating means). I also didn't check for normality of the responses. If I was lazy, I'd do:

```
> t.test(subset(d, condition == 3, select = rating), subset(d, condition == 4, select = rating))
t = 0.59428, df = 237.19, p-value = 0.5529
```

So, I thought, a nonparametric test such as Mann-Whitney U test seems logical – at least this is what some people have used for Likert scales:

```
> library(coin)
> wilcox_test(rating ~ condition, distribution = "exact", data = filter(d, condition %in% c(3,4)))
Z = 0.62165, p-value = 0.5353
```

Is this the correct way to go?

How would I go about considering the subject being a random factor? I know the ratings can be paired by subject, but the tests do not consider this yet.